# C# - Look up a users manager in active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

Started using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace, to perform the lookup on a user in active directory (AD). **I also need the user's manager**, but I seem to have hit a bump in the road using this namespace. Current code to get a person:

```cs
class Person {
    // Fields
    public string GivenName = null;
    public string Surname = null;
    public string DistinguishedName = null;
    public string Email = null;
    public string MangerDistinguishedName = null;  // Unable to set this

    // Constructor
    public Person(string userName) {
        UserPrincipal user = null;

        try {
            user = GetUser(userName);

            if (user != null) {
                this.GivenName = user.GivenName;
                this.Surname = user.Surname;
                this.DistinguishedName = user.DistinguishedName;
                this.Email = user.EmailAddress;
                this.MangerDistinguishedName = user.<NO SUCH PROPERTY TO FIND A MANAGER'S DISTINGUISHED NAME>
            }
            else {
                throw new MissingPersonException("Person not found");
            }
        }
        catch (MissingPersonException ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(
                ex.Message
                , ex.reason
                , MessageBoxButtons.OK
                , MessageBoxIcon.Error
            );
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(
                ex.Message
                , "Error: Possible connection failure, or permissions failure to search for the username provided."
                , MessageBoxButtons.OK
                , MessageBoxIcon.Error
            );
        }
        finally {
            user.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Execute search for the person

```cs
    private UserPrincipal GetUser(string userName) {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);

        return user;
    }
```

**What is another way to directly access the distinguished name of the manager of a particular user?**

- Possible partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498908/looping-through-active-directory-to-get-managers-and-direct-reports) in VB, but I see nothing about referring to managers.
- Another possible partial one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546871/system-directoryservices-vs-system-directoryservices-accountmanagement), again, nothing about managers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up and using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace, you can easily extend the existing `UserPrincipal` class to get at more advanced properties, like `Manager` etc.

Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you just define a derived class based on `UserPrincipal`, and then you define your additional properties you want:

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]
public class UserPrincipalEx : UserPrincipal
{
    // Inplement the constructor using the base class constructor. 
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context) : base(context)
    { }

    // Implement the constructor with initialization parameters.    
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context,
                         string samAccountName,
                         string password,
                         bool enabled) : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled)
    {} 

    // Create the "Department" property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("department")]
    public string Department
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("department").Length != 1)
                return string.Empty;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("department")[0];
        }
        set { ExtensionSet("department", value); }
    }

    // Create the "Manager" property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("manager")]
    public string Manager
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("manager").Length != 1)
                return string.Empty;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("manager")[0];
        }
        set { ExtensionSet("manager", value); }
    }

    // Implement the overloaded search method FindByIdentity.
    public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, string identityValue)
    {
        return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), identityValue);
    }

    // Implement the overloaded search method FindByIdentity. 
    public static new UserPrincipalEx FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, string identityValue)
    {
        return (UserPrincipalEx)FindByIdentityWithType(context, typeof(UserPrincipalEx), identityType, identityValue);
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the "extended" version of the `UserPrincipalEx` in your code:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // Search the directory for the new object. 
    UserPrincipalEx inetPerson = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "someuser");

    // you can easily access the Manager or Department now
    string department = inetPerson.Department;
    string manager = inetPerson.Manager;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  It doesn't work, for me.  UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity does not return a UserPrincipalEx object, and casting to UserPrincipalEx causes an InvalidCastException.

Comment: @Naikrovek: sorry - my mistake - I had cut out a bit too much code from my (much longer) sample. I had missed the two overloaded `FindByIdentity` and `FindByIdentityWithType` methods - I added those to my code snippet - and yes, with this code, I just checked it against Win Server 2008 R2 Active Directory and it works fine for me.