# C# - Look up direct reports in active directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I am using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement to manage my login user account.

I am able to get information for login user, but not able to get direct reports user id based on manager.

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
```

I have refer to this link: [C# - Look up a users manager in active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608241/c-sharp-look-up-a-users-manager-in-active-directory)

But still didn't get any clue. Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out the directory property for direct reports("directReports").

Just to add a new directory property as below:

```
    // Create the "Direct Report" property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("directReports")]
    public List<string> DirectReports
    {
        get
        {
            var directReportsName = new List<string>();
            if (ExtensionGet("directReports").Length == 0)
                return directReportsName;

            for (int i = 0; i < ExtensionGet("directReports").Length; i++)
            {
                string userString = (string)ExtensionGet("directReports")[i];
                //example of userString = CN=name,OU=Users,OU=department,OU=AP,OU=Software,DC=company,DC=priv,DC=company,DC=com
                //split by comma
                var tempCN = userString.Split(',').First();
                var tempName = tempCN.Split('=');
                var userName= tempName[1];

                directReportsAlias.Add(userName);
            }
            return directReportsName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is ExtensionGet?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.extensionget?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score 0):

I have designed class for active directory search.

This class support.

1. Search Employee By Same Account Name
2. Search Employee By Employee Id
3. Search Employee By Employee Code
4. Search Employee By Employee Email
5. Search Employee Manage
6. Search Team Member

**CLASS CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace UAT.COMMON
{
    #region RefranceHelpers
    /*
        //https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/active-directory-and-net/
        //https://ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm
        //https://ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm
    */
    #endregion

    public enum SearchBy
    {
        StartNTID=0,
    }
    public class ManageDirectoryServices : IDisposable
    {
        public ContextType contextType = ContextType.Domain;
        public PrincipalContext Context { get; protected set; }
        public UserPrincipal User { get; protected set; }
        public UserPrincipal Manager { get; protected set; }
        public bool IsManager { get; protected set; }
        public List<UserPrincipal> DirectReports { get; protected set; }

        public class AuthenticationResult
        {
            public AuthenticationResult()
            {
                IdentityError = new List<IdentityError>();
                IsSuccess = IdentityError.Count > 0;
            }
            public List<IdentityError> IdentityError { get; private set; }
            public String RoleName { get; private set; }
            public Boolean IsSuccess { get; set; }
            public ManageDirectoryServices Context { get; set; }
        }

        public ManageDirectoryServices()
        {
            Context = new PrincipalContext(contextType);
            DirectReports = new List<UserPrincipal>();
        }

        public ManageDirectoryServices(string ntid)
        {
            Context = new PrincipalContext(contextType);
            DirectReports = new List<UserPrincipal>();
            GetEmployeeByNTID(NormalizeNTID(ntid));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ntid">This is SamAccountName</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public ManageDirectoryServices GetEmployeeByNTID(string ntid)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ntid)) return null;
            UserPrincipal searchTemplate = new UserPrincipal(Context)
            {
                SamAccountName = ntid
            };
            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(searchTemplate);
            User = (UserPrincipal)ps.FindOne();
            return this;
        }


        public ManageDirectoryServices GetEmployee(string strSearch,string prop)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strSearch)) return this;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prop)) return this;

            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();
            search.Filter = String.Format("(cn={0})", strSearch);
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(prop);
            var result = search.FindAll();

            if (result != null)
            {
                int directReports = result.Count; //result.Properties["displayname"].Count;
                if (directReports < 0) return null;

                for (int counter = 0; counter < directReports; counter++)
                {
                    var user = (string)result[counter].Properties["givenname"][counter];
                    var reporte = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Context, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, user);
                    this.DirectReports.Add(reporte);
                    IsManager = true;
                }
                return this;
            }
            return null;
        }



        public ManageDirectoryServices GetEmployee(UserPrincipal searchTemplate)
        {
            if (searchTemplate == null) return null;
            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(searchTemplate);
            User = (UserPrincipal)ps.FindOne();
            return this;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="NTID">This is SamAccountName</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool IsUserExist(string NTID)
        {
            var data = GetEmployeeByNTID(NormalizeNTID(NTID));
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data?.User?.SamAccountName);
        }

        public bool IsUserExist()
        {
            var data = User;
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data?.SamAccountName);
        }

        public ManageDirectoryServices GetEmployeeByEmail(string email)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email)) return null;
            UserPrincipal searchTemplate = new UserPrincipal(Context)
            {
                EmailAddress = email
            };
            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(searchTemplate);
            User = (UserPrincipal)ps.FindOne();
            return this;
        }

        public ManageDirectoryServices GetEmployeeByEmpId(string employeeId)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(employeeId)) return null;
            UserPrincipal searchTemplate = new UserPrincipal(Context)
            {
                EmployeeId = employeeId
            };
            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(searchTemplate);
            User = (UserPrincipal)ps.FindOne();
            return this;
        }

        public ManageDirectoryServices GetManager()
        {
            if (this.User == null) return null;
            DirectoryEntry ManagerDE = this.User.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            var manager = ManagerDE.Properties["manager"].Value.ToString();
            UserPrincipal oManager = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Context, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, manager);
            this.Manager = oManager;
            return this;
        }

        public ManageDirectoryServices GetDirectReports()
        {
            if (this.User == null) return this;
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();
            search.Filter = String.Format("(cn={0})", this.User.SamAccountName);
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("directReports");
            SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
            if (result != null)
            {
                int directReports = result.Properties["directReports"].Count;
                if (directReports < 0) return null;

                for (int counter = 0; counter < directReports; counter++)
                {
                    var user = (string)result.Properties["directReports"][counter];
                    var reporte = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(Context, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, user);
                    this.DirectReports.Add(reporte);
                    IsManager = true;
                }
                return this;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public string NormalizeNTID(string Id)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Id)) return "";
            return Id.Trim().ToUpper().Replace(@"\", "")
                .Replace("\\", "")
                .Replace("/", "")
                .Replace("//", "")
                .Replace("MS", "")
                .Replace("MS//", "")
                .Replace("MS\\", "");
        }

        public AuthenticationResult SignIn(string ntid, string password)
        {
            var NormalizeNTID = this.NormalizeNTID(ntid);
            bool IsAuthenticated = false;
            IdentityError identityError = new IdentityError();
            ManageDirectoryServices context = null;
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = new AuthenticationResult();
            var IsSuccess = Context.ValidateCredentials(NormalizeNTID, password, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
            context = GetEmployeeByNTID(NormalizeNTID);
            if (IsSuccess)
            {
                if (context.User != null)
                {
                    IsAuthenticated = true;
                    this.User = context.User;
                    authenticationResult.Context = context;
                    authenticationResult.IsSuccess = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!IsAuthenticated || User == null)
                {
                    authenticationResult.IdentityError.Add(new IdentityError
                    {
                        Code = "InCorrectUserAndPassword",
                        Description = "Username or Password is not correct"
                    });
                }

                if (context.User.IsAccountLockedOut())
                {
                    authenticationResult.IdentityError.Add(new IdentityError
                    {
                        Code = "YourAccountIsLocked",
                        Description = "Your account is locked."
                    });
                }

                if (context.User.Enabled.HasValue && User.Enabled.Value == false)
                {
                    authenticationResult.IdentityError.Add(identityError = new IdentityError
                    {
                        Code = "YourAccountIsDisabled",
                        Description = "Your account is disabled"
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    authenticationResult.IdentityError.Add(new IdentityError
                    {
                        Code = "InvalidLogin",
                        Description = "In valid login!! Please try again"
                    });
                }
            }
            return authenticationResult;
        }

        #region ************Async Envelope**************

        public async Task<ManageDirectoryServices> GetEmployeeByNTIDAsync(string ntid)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => GetEmployeeByNTID(ntid));
        }

        public async Task<ManageDirectoryServices> GetEmployeeByEmailAsync(string email)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => GetEmployeeByEmail(email));
        }

        public async Task<ManageDirectoryServices> GetEmployeeByEmpIdAsync(string employeeId)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => GetEmployeeByEmpId(employeeId));
        }

        public async Task<ManageDirectoryServices> GetManagerAsync()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => GetManager());
        }

        public async Task<ManageDirectoryServices> GetDirectReportsAsync()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => GetDirectReports());
        }

        public async Task<AuthenticationResult> SignInAsync(string ntid, string password)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => SignIn(ntid, password));
        }

        #endregion

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
        }

    }
}
```

**How To Use**

```
[TestMethod]
        public void ContractorInitialsSuccess()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices(MSID);
            var context = manageDirectoryServices.User;
            Assert.AreEqual(MSID, context.SamAccountName);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void SignInSuccess()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices();
            var context = manageDirectoryServices.SignIn(MSID,MSPASSWORD);
            Assert.AreEqual(EMAIL, context.Context.User.EmailAddress);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetEmployeeByNTIDSuccess()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices();
            var context = manageDirectoryServices.GetEmployeeByNTID(MSID);
            Assert.AreEqual(MSID, context.User.SamAccountName);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetManagerSuccess()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices();
            var context = manageDirectoryServices.GetEmployeeByNTID(MSID);
            var manager = context.GetManager();
            Assert.AreEqual(MANAGER_NTID, context.Manager.SamAccountName);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetReportesSuccess()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices();
            var context = manageDirectoryServices.GetEmployeeByNTID(MSID);
            var repcontext = context.GetDirectReports();
            var flag = repcontext.DirectReports.Count > 0 ? true : false;
            Assert.AreEqual(true, flag);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetEmployeeByEmailSuccess()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices();
            var context = manageDirectoryServices.GetEmployeeByEmail(EMAIL);
            Assert.AreEqual(EMAIL, context.User.EmailAddress);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetEmployeeByEmployeeIdSuccess()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices();
            var context = manageDirectoryServices.GetEmployeeByEmpId(EMPLOYEEID);
            Assert.AreEqual(EMPLOYEEID, context.User.EmployeeId);
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void IsUserExistSuccess()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices();
            var IsExist = manageDirectoryServices.IsUserExist(MSID);
            Assert.AreEqual(true, IsExist);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void IsUserExistFail()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices();
            var IsExist = manageDirectoryServices.IsUserExist("invalidid");
            Assert.AreEqual(false, IsExist);
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void GetEmployeeSuccess()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices();
            var searchTemplate = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal(manageDirectoryServices.Context) {
                SamAccountName= MSID,
                EmailAddress=EMAIL,
                EmployeeId=EMPLOYEEID
            };
            var context = manageDirectoryServices.GetEmployee(searchTemplate);
            Assert.AreEqual(MSID, context.User.SamAccountName);
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void GetEmployeeNameSuccess0()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices();
            var repcontext = manageDirectoryServices.GetEmployee("abhishek", "givenname");
            var flag = repcontext.DirectReports.Count > 0 ? true : false;
            Assert.AreEqual(true, flag);
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void GetEmployeeNameSuccess1()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices();
            var repcontext = manageDirectoryServices.GetEmployee("abhishek", "name");
            var flag = repcontext.DirectReports.Count > 0 ? true : false;
            Assert.AreEqual(true, flag);
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void GetEmployeeNameSuccess2()
        {
            ManageDirectoryServices manageDirectoryServices = new ManageDirectoryServices();
            var repcontext = manageDirectoryServices.GetEmployee("abhishek", "displayname");
            var flag = repcontext.DirectReports.Count > 0 ? true : false;
            Assert.AreEqual(true, flag);
        }
```