# C# AD Get Manager details ( including name, email and sam account number)

Tags: c#, active-directory

I searched to see if there is a way to get the manager details of an employee , I know we can get the first, last name but is there a way to get employee ID, email of the manager in AD using C#

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608241/c-sharp-look-up-a-users-manager-in-active-directory ?

Comment: You can get anything from AD in C#. How is a matter of your exact schema, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DirectorySearcher.AttributeScopeQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.attributescopequery(v=vs.110).aspx?) is the answer to your question.

**Code:**

```
Dim user As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://UserDN")
Dim src As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(user, "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person))")
src.AttributeScopeQuery = "manager"
src.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")
src.PropertiesToLoad.Add("employeeID") 
src.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")
src.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")

For Each res As SearchResult In src.FindAll()
     Console.WriteLine(res.Properties("SAMAccountName")(0))
     Console.WriteLine(res.Properties("employeeID")(0))
     Console.WriteLine(res.Properties("mail")(0))
     Console.WriteLine(res.Properties("name")(0))
Next

Console.ReadLine()
```