# C# - Get all users from active directory are under a manager

Tags: c#, active-directory

I need to implement code in c# to get users Active directory who work under a given manager. My below code returns only level below user i.e. subsequent below level employees are not fetched.

My Primary requirement is to prepare an organization chart (using google Org chart).

```
public void GetAllUsers()
{
    //List<User> users = new List<User>();
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE");
        root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + root.Properties["defaultNamingContext"][0]);
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(root);
        //search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";

        search.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(manager={0}))","CN=abcde a hoss,OU=Policy Excluded Users,OU=HO,DC=sampledomain,DC=com");

        search.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedname");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("manager");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("title");
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
        //ds.ServerPageTimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        //ds.Filter = string.Format(expression, userDN);

        SearchResultCollection r = search.FindAll();
        if (r != null)
        {
            Response.Write("<table border='1'><tr><th>Distinguished Name</th><th>Display Name</th><th>Manager</th><th>Title</th><th>sAMAccountName</th></tr>");
            foreach (SearchResult result in r)
            {
                ADUser user = new ADUser();
                user.DistinguishedName = (result.Properties["distinguishedname"].Count > 0) ? Convert.ToString(result.Properties["distinguishedname"][0]) : "";
                user.DisplayName = (result.Properties["displayname"].Count > 0) ? Convert.ToString(result.Properties["displayname"][0]) : "";
                user.Manager_DistinguishedName = (result.Properties["manager"].Count > 0) ? Convert.ToString(result.Properties["manager"][0]) : "";
                user.Title = (result.Properties["title"].Count > 0) ? Convert.ToString(result.Properties["title"][0]) : "";
                user.sAMAccountName = (result.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Count > 0) ? Convert.ToString(result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0]) : "";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Manager_DistinguishedName))
                {
                    Response.Write("<tr><td>" + user.DistinguishedName + " </td><td> " + user.DisplayName + " </td><td> " + user.Manager_DistinguishedName + " </td><td> " + user.Title + " </td><td> " + user.sAMAccountName + "</td></tr>");                    
                    users.Add(user);
                }
            }

            Response.Write("</table>");

        }


        hdnData.Value = js.Serialize(users);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Also when try to get all users from AD using below expression it returns those users also who are not mapped.

```
search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
```

As mentioned above am getting only 1 level below employees and not further down the hirarchy. Consider this example;
A is the top manager.
B and C report to manager A.
Whereas D and E report to B further F reports to C. 
Now when i pass details of A i get only users B and C.

Kindly let know what am i missing.

Comment: This might seem like an obvious question (and apologies if you have already tried this), but are you running the program with sufficient privileges to see the whole set of users? I've been caught out by this before, but not in AD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Look up a users manager in active directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608241/c-sharp-look-up-a-users-manager-in-active-directory)